# Numpy block matrix assignment with integer array indexing

Tags: python, numpy

Is there an elegant way (without loops) to do this kind of assignment with numpy indexing?

```
import numpy as np

m = 3
n = 5
small_matrix = np.random.randn(m, n)
big_matrix = np.zeros((100, 100))
row_indices = [3, 16, 9]
col_indices = [31, 45, 69, 71, 83]

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        big_matrix[row_indices[i], col_indices[j]] = small_matrix[i, j]
```

Comment: There are lots of almost-duplicates: `np.ix_` is the way to go, i.e. `big_matrix[np.ix_(row_indices, column_indices)] = small_matrix`.

Comment: @DSM Thanks! I didn't find those.

Comment: I cheated because I knew what function to look for. ;-)